# Suppress message in minibuffer when a buffer is saved?

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area, message

Whenever a buffer is saved, a message is displayed in minibuffer.

> Wrote foo.bar

I use [real-auto-save](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/real-auto-save) to save modified buffers every 5 seconds. Due to this minibuffer is getting spammed. Sometimes, when I am looking at useful info(like signature,  errors or something else), this message overrides it.

Is there a way to disable printing this message in minibuffer?

Comment: Try `(let (message-log-max) (save-buffer))` to disable *all* messages during `save-buffer`.

Comment: You should submit a feature request to the github issue queue for that package.

Comment: @xuchunyang let  binding  is not suppressing message.

Comment: @phils I wrote that package and dont  know how to suppress messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following

```
(defmacro with-suppressed-message (&rest body)
  "Suppress new messages temporarily in the echo area and the `*Messages*' buffer while BODY is evaluated."
  (declare (indent 0))
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    `(with-temp-message (or (current-message) "") ,@body)))

(with-suppressed-message (save-buffer))
```

instead of `(save-buffer)`

Comment: This code comes from http://qiita.com/itiut@github/items/d917eafd6ab255629346 , though in Japanese.

Comment: What's the `(declare (indent 0))` for?

Comment: Thats not required @JeanPierre

Comment: Looks to me like the let binding should be part of the expanded form.

Comment: This did not helped for the `(save-some-buffers t)`

Answer (score 7):

As was pointed out by @phils the "Wrote file" comes from `write-region`. If you don't use the `inhibit-message` variable introduced in Emacs 25, you could replace the original `write-region` with a function that sets `VISIT` to neither t nor nil nor a string. As the docstring of `write-region` tells us, this will avoid displaying the message. In the following example the `write-region` is replaced temporarily using `cl-letf`:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(fset 'original-write-region (symbol-function 'write-region))
(defun silent-write-region (start end filename &optional append
                                  visit lockname mustbenew)
  "Suppress the \"Wrote file\" message in `write-region'."
  (original-write-region start end filename append 'nomsg lockname mustbenew))

(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'write-region)
           #'silent-write-region))
  (save-buffer (current-buffer))
  ;; take care of mtime changes
  (set-visited-file-modtime)
  (set-buffer-modified-p nil))
```

Comment: Huh. The overloading of `VISIT` isn't the most obvious thing, but I'm *really* not sure how I missed it in the C code -- where it's clearly labelled `quietly` (and has been for 22 years...)

Comment: For people skimming: `inhibit-message` is the key in Emacs 25+

Comment: I added it into my init file but still save message shows up

Answer (score 3):

There is a var named save-silently in files.el. if you set the var to t I think the message will not show again.

```
(defvar save-silently nil
  "If non-nil, avoid messages when saving files.
  Error-related messages will still be printed, but all other
  messages will not.")
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: maybe the message you saw is error message. `Error-related messages will still be printed, `

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:**

To suppress messages in the code you write:

- use `with-temp-message`.

  - problem of let-binding `inhibit-message` to nil: current message is still cleared.
- let-bind `message-log-max` to nil if you want to disable message logging in
  `*Messages*`.

(You can write a wrapper as suggested in [@Haruyasu Ueda's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30032/14573))

To suppress messages from any single function:

```
(defun suppress-message-advice-around (fun &rest args)
  (let (message-log-max)
    (with-temp-message (or (current-message) "")
      (apply fun args))))
;; example: suppress any messages from `save-buffer'
(advice-add 'save-buffer :around 'suppress-message-advice-around)
;; undo:
(advice-remove 'save-buffer 'suppress-message-advice-around)
```

(If you want to know where does a message come from: use
[debug-on-message](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html).)

---

---

the original answer

#### Just clear the minibuffer afterward.

**Don't need to suppress, just clear the minibuffer afterward,** if you just don't want to see the message showing in minibuffer.

```
(defun clear-message ()
  (message nil))
(advice-add 'real-auto-save-buffers :after 'clear-message)
;; replace `real-auto-save-buffers' with the function whose messages
;; should not show in the minibuffer.
```

---

From the manual of `message`:

> If the first argument is nil or the empty string, the function clears
> any existing message;

Basically, what `(message nil)` does is **clearing the current message from the echo area**, and it doesn't affect the messages in `*Messages*`. It works out well when you don't want to see the annoying messages keep showing in the minibuffer.

And, a good thing is, when you are editing the minibuffer (e.g `M-x` or `find-file`) and a message shows up, normally you need to type something to make the message disappear. If `(message nil)` is called, the message will disappear immediately and you can see the original content of the minibufer.

---

In general, if you don't want to see a particular function showing messages in the minibuffer, you don't need to suppress the messages when it is called, just call `(message nil)` afterward to clear the current message in minibuffer.

---

#### if you want to suppress the messages

Replacing the `message` function temporarily is much more straight forward:

```
(defmacro no-message (&rest body)
  "Eval BODY, with `message' doing nothing."
  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message)
              (lambda (&rest args)
                nil)))
     (progn ,@body)))

(no-message
 (message "meaningless")  ; do nothing
 (print [1 2 3])  ; not affected
 (save-buffer))  ; won't display messages in minibuffer
```

Comment: It seems like ChillarAnand wants to see the message that was previously there, not just that they don't want to see the "Wrote foo.bar" message.

Comment: `(message nil)` doesn't touch the existing messages, it just clears the current message from the minibuffer. I have edited my answer. @zck

Comment: Oh, I see now, `(message nil)` doesn't bring back the message that was in the minibuffer when the save message shows up. In this case, maybe `current-messge` can help.