# How to suppress the save buffer message in the minibuffer in Doom Emacs? (using Emacs 27)

Tags: doom

I'm using the [`super-save`](https://github.com/bbatsov/super-save) package which saves the buffer when an Emacs frame loses focus and it's spamming the minibuffer with '`file written`' messages, which gets distracting.

I want to suppress this message in the minibuffer, so it doesn't appear anymore. I've tried to come up with solutions from this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14706/suppress-message-in-minibuffer-when-a-buffer-is-saved) but I couldn't get it working. The answers also seem to be quite old, which makes me wonder about a more modern solution.

It would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction, specifically for the Doom Emacs distribution using Emacs 27.

[image: Doom saving buffer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following to hide "Wrote ..." messages. I use regular GNU Emacs though.

```
(defun sb/inhibit-message-call-orig-fun (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Hide messages appearing in ORIG-FUN, forward ARGS."
  (let ((inhibit-message t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'write-region :around #'sb/inhibit-message-call-orig-fun)
```

I use `super-save` but I do not see the above messages in my minibuffer. You can give the above snippet a try. If the above does not work, you can try adding the following to the above snippet.

```
(advice-add 'save-buffer :around #'sb/inhibit-message-call-orig-fun)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both snippets combined worked.